# Was there Nazi Collaboration at an Institutional level in Poland?

Tags: europe, nazi-germany, jews, poland, holocaust

Following recent legal regulations in Poland prohibiting any association of Polish culpability with the Holocaust and concentration camps, the question that arises is whether there was any Polish collaboration with the Nazi regime at a national or at any institutional level?

Is there evidence of the government, bureaucrats or public sector institutions in Poland actively collaborating with the Nazis, and of them conspiring against their Jewish population and, if so, in what way and to what extent was it carried out willingly?

Comment: I'm voting to close, despite the fact that I think this is a good question. As it stands, it's extraordinarily broad. There's a large literature on collaboration in lots of countries: France and the Netherlands are the two that most recently spring to mind, as does the collaboration of local populations in non-autonomous regions like Ukraine. I would suggest asking this as a series of questions, enabling you to focus on different places. I would certainly ask about Denmark separately, as there's much misinformation concerning Denmark specifically.

Comment: Ok I have edited it so that the focus is on Poland

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia:Collaboration in German-occupied Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration_in_German-occupied_Poland)

Answer (score 3):

Both sides were basically against this [idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaboration_in_German-occupied_Poland).

While it was occupied, Poland never formally "surrendered" to Germany, making it hard for the Germans to deal with any semblance of the Polish government. Several high level leaders who were approached by the Germans to collaborate declined to do so. Several low level Polish leaders who offered their services to Germany had their offers declined. In the end, the negotiations foundered because Germany wanted, if not "unconditional surrender," something very close to it, with no real concessions given to the Poles.

The main public institutions that collaborated with Germany in Poland (after a fashion) were the [Judenrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judenrat), the Jewish councils that the Germans set up in the ghettos when the Jews were forced into them.